# No candidate version found for sudo

Tags: linux, debian, apt, sudo

When I tried to install `sudo` in Debian 8.2 via `aptitude install sudo` I got an error: `No candidate version found for sudo`. The source list is standart.

Here is the Source list:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Comment: Did you `aptitude update` first?

Comment: Yes. I do aptitude update and aptitude upgrade.

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy; apt-cache policy sudo`